# Hibernate not creating new table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, dropwizard

I have the following table

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "School")


@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class School implements  Serializable,  Comparable<School>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @JsonProperty
 @JsonProperty
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
long id;

}
```

Here is the yaml file that sets the hibernate config to create new datbase

```
 charSet: UTF-8
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create
    hibernate.show_sql: true
```

I read many questions addressing similar issue but I dont see why this table would be ignored by hibernate

Upon trying out different solutions, it appears that only two tables arent being updated or recreated. Could this be because of the association between them?

Here is the second class associated with it

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
@SecondaryTable(name = "thirdTable", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="thirdtablepk_id", referencedColumnName="id"))


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)


public class Student  implements Comparable<Student>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;

    @ManyToOne
    School school;
}
```

Comment: `@Table(name = "Scool")` vs `@Table(name = "School")`?

Comment: good catch, it was a typo here. Not in my actual code :(

Comment: Why use Hibernate specific DDL property when there are JPA standard property javax.persistence.XXX names you could use?

Comment: Hi Neil, this is a dropwizard application and I am following their documentation. ,  https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/core/Person.java  can you point me to an example of what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean for the unique ids? I am already using it, I have tried both

Answer (score 0):

I guess since you used

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create

Once the table is created it won't be created again. In order to drop and create table eevry time you need to use belwo configuration.

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create-drop

Hope this resolves your doubt.

Comment: I have tried this as well. I m almost sure its something in the classs thats making hibernate ignore it

Comment: It only is not working for this table and one more table, no changes to schema are reflected. Do you think this is because of association between these two tables? I've edited the question with the details

Comment: I see th code you have to add @OnetoMany relation in the School entity too.